# Split dataframe values and put in a group in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a column of a dataframe like:

```
df <- structure(list(ingredients = structure(c("en:xylitol", "en:water,en:sugar,en:glucose-fructose-syrup,en:fructose,en:glucose,fr:dioxyde-de-carbone,en:acid,en:citric-acid,en:natural-flavouring,en:flavouring,fr:arome-quinine,fr:quinine", 
"en:sugar,en:corn-syrup,fr:sirop-de-mais-a-teneur-elevee-en-fructose,en:citric-acid,en:natural-and-artificial-flavouring,en:artificial-flavouring,en:natural-flavouring,en:flavouring,en:colour,fr:rouge-40,fr:bleu-1", 
"pt:semoule-de-ble-dur,pt:pesto,pt:basilic,pt:fromage-en-poudre,pt:ail-et-epinars,pt:basilic-contient-du-gluten-et-des-derives-de-lait", 
"pt:pimenta-branca", "en:water,es:pasta-de-almendras-tostadas,en:sugar", 
"en:water,es:zumo-de-chufas,en:sugar,en:dextrose,en:glucose,es:estabilizantes,es:412,es:carragenanos,es:e-407,es:carboximetil-celulosa,es:e-466,es:monodigliceridos-de-acidos-grasos,en:mono-and-diglycerides-of-fatty-acids,en:emulsifier,en:flavouring,en:guar-gum,es:e", 
"es:aceitunas-cacerena,en:water,en:salt,en:stabiliser,es:579,es:categoria,es:i,es:calibre,es:gluconato-ferroso,es:e,es:240,es:260", 
"en:carbonated-water,en:water,en:sugar,en:colour,fr:caramel-e150d,en:natural-flavouring,en:flavouring,en:acid,en:phosphoric-acid,fr:extrait-de-genepi,fr:cafeine", 
"en:pear,en:fruit,es:variedad,es:70-mm,es:conferencia,es:categoria-i,es:calibre,es:65"
), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to split each row by "," separator and put the separated output in a group.

For example:

```
en:water,es:pasta-de-almendras-tostadas,en:sugar
```

will turn into

```
group ingredient
1     en:water
1     es:pasta-de-almendras-tostadas
1     en:sugar
```

The next thing is to delete the prefix of `XX:`

Please advise how to do this?

Comment: Do you neeed `df %>% mutate(group = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(ingredients, sep=",")`

Comment: The grouping part is not clear

Comment: @akrun as always great answer, I didn't see this function please post as an answer

Comment: It is not giving the expected output you showed

Comment: @akrun actually it does

Comment: @akrun it would if one added `%>% select(2, 1)` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` after adding a sequence column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(group = row_number()) %>%
    separate_rows(ingredients, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `strsplit` and add a group column according to list number, finally `rbind` the thing.

```
l <- strsplit(df$ingredients, ",")

res <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, sapply(seq(l), function(x) 
  cbind(group=x, ingredient=l[[x]]))))
head(res)
#   group                ingredient
# 1     1                en:xylitol
# 2     2                  en:water
# 3     2                  en:sugar
# 4     2 en:glucose-fructose-syrup
# 5     2               en:fructose
# 6     2                en:glucose
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer including the removal of the prefix:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    mutate(ingredients = str_split(ingredients, ","),
           row_num = row_number()) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    mutate(ingredients = str_remove(ingredients, "^[^:]+(:)"))

#> # A tibble: 82 x 2
#>    row_num ingredients           
#>      <int> <chr>                 
#>  1       1 xylitol               
#>  2       2 water                 
#>  3       2 sugar                 
#>  4       2 glucose-fructose-syrup
#>  5       2 fructose              
#>  6       2 glucose               
#>  7       2 dioxyde-de-carbone    
#>  8       2 acid                  
#>  9       2 citric-acid           
#> 10       2 natural-flavouring    
#> # … with 72 more rows
```

Comment: Can you please explain the regex?

Comment: @SteveS the regex matches everything up to the first `:` and `str_remove()` replaces it with `""`. There is a way to include the `:` but I couldn't figure it out, hence the second iteration where I only remove the `:`.

Comment: I see, but I am trying to understand the regex step by step:
^[^:] means start of string excluding the : 
+ any number of times
(?=:) - what does it mean Positive Lookahead

Comment: @SteveS, apologies. Yes `^[^:]+` mean match everything from the beginning of the string that is not `:` and if it happens multiple times. I have edited my answer to be more concise where `(:)` means to match any `:` and include it.

Comment: So positive lookahead means that match the ```:``` but only if it exists?

Comment: @SteveS I removed the positive look ahead in favor of matching `:`. I'm not quite sure what the positive look ahead was doing, I had the regex saved in some previous code where I was matching everything up to the first underscore.

Comment: Have a look on my code in my answer I have used different regex

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`:

```r
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x){
                        unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))}), 
          by = seq.int(nrow(df))]
```

or just using `base`:

```r
stack(setNames(strsplit(df$ingredients,','), seq.int(nrow(df))))
```

or using `splitstackshape` package:

```r
require(splitstackshape)

cSplit(cbind(seq.int(nrow(df)), df), "ingredients", ",", "long")

#>    seq.int(nrow(df))               ingredients
#> 1:                 1                en:xylitol
#> 2:                 2                  en:water
#> 3:                 2                  en:sugar
#> 4:                 2 en:glucose-fructose-syrup
#> 5:                 2               en:fructose
#> 6:                 2                en:glucose
#...# … with 76 more rows (manually trimmed the output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @akrun's suggestion of separate_rows function I have just used the following code with the regex `^[a-z]{2}:` that means that I want to filter at the beginning of each value the first 2 characters `a-z` and a column (`:`).

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(ingredients, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ingredients = str_remove(ingredients, pattern = "^[a-z]{2}:")) %>%
  dplyr::distinct(ingredients, .keep_all = TRUE)
```